# I get this error while trying to "update-database" after adding migration

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I get this error after trying to update database from package manager console. Here is some code. Class User is already in database and i am trying to migrate class Poslovnica to server.

There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'User' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Poslovnica_User_UserID'.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

```
 public class Poslovnica
{
    public int PoslovnicaID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Naziv { get; set; }

    public string Adresa { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int? UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I already added some classes that have foreign key UserID int them and didnt  have any problems

```
 public class User
{
    public int userID { get; set; }

    

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string ime { get; set; }
   
    
}
```

model builder from migration

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("ClassLibrary1.Models.Poslovnica", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("PoslovnicaID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<string>("Adresa");

                b.Property<string>("Naziv")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Property<int?>("UserID");

                b.HasKey("PoslovnicaID");

                b.HasIndex("UserID");

                b.ToTable("Poslovnica");
            });
```

migration builder

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Poslovnica",
            columns: table => new
            {
                PoslovnicaID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Naziv = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Adresa = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                UserID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Poslovnica", x => x.PoslovnicaID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Poslovnica_User_UserID",
                    column: x => x.UserID,
                    principalTable: "User",
                    principalColumn: "userID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1 to 1 relationship between `Poslovnica` and `User` but the foreign key in `Poslovnica` doesn't match the primary key in `User`.

Rename the property `userID` in `User` to `UserID` to match the foreign key since you're going by the convention so they must match in order for ef core to pick up on the relationship. and re-update

**Edit**

Probably the `UserID` is not recognized as a primary key in the table `Users`
Add the following attributes to the `UserID` :

```
 public class User
{
    [Key] 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int UserID { get; set; }   
}
```

And update your database.

Comment: Thanks for response! I did it and i still get the same error message

Comment: I tried it, still same error. I dont think there is problem with user table because i had allready connected it with few other tables with same connection

Comment: @sasko You do know that you have to remove the created migration and create a new one after the change right? Then you update the db

Comment: yes,  i have some old migrations that i dont want to loose but i deleted all migrations that have "Poslovnica" table in them

Comment: anyways thanks for helping me, i created  new database and can migrate all classes in it without errors  so now i know that there is somewhere conflict in migrations

Comment: @sasko Glad to help! i expected that the new migrations is conflicting with the older ones 
and i was about to suggest creating a test database. Anyway glad you solved your problem.